# SAS proq sql character (stored as days since 1960) to Date

Tags: sql, date, sas, format, proc

I'm importing an Excel spreadsheet using SAS EG7.12. One date column is unusual when I pull it in - the formats are quite varied. Examples of the values:

- **43620** *(days since 1960)*
- **11/4/2019**
- **Wed 11/13/2019**

I imported this field as text, figuring I could simply clean up the various formats in SAS (turn the chaos into sanity). There are plenty of examples of converting a character 11/4/2019 to a SAS date. Sadly, I can't figure out how to store the 43620 as a date, even though it's already in the format that SAS Dates like.

was hoping it would be as simple as (within proc sql)

```
putn(A,date.) as mydate
```

where A is the column name. SAS error on that is 
**ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, *.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your variable really named A?  Your problem is most likely that you have mixed date (aka numeric) and character cells in the same column of your spreadsheet. Make sure the cells in the columns are all of the same type.  A SAS dataset is not a spreadsheet where you can put anything into any cell.

Comment: It is A! I didn't use GetNames cause the Excel column names are off-the-wall bizarre. Also, yes, there are mixed values in the column, which I would prefer dealing with in SAS instead of editing the spreadsheet.

Comment: Convert the strings that look like integers into numbers, `input(a,32.)`, and add the negative number '30DEC1899'd to adjust for the difference in the base value used for dates.  For the other strings use an appropriate informat based on what they look like.  You could try `ANYDTDTE` informat since it can read and make a good guess for many strings that look like dates.

Comment: Also make sure not to read the names as part of the data as that will make even clean numeric columns look like they have a cell with string data.